# Nvd3 chart different time zone

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm struggling now with a time problem.

I'm using the **NVD3 library** to create my chart, I calculate all the chart data at the **server side**.

The problem is that the time range at the graph is according to my computer time (GMT+3) and **not my machine (UTC)**. How can I fetch it to be UTC and not GMT+3?

What can I do?

**I'm adding my code if it can help**

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart().x(function(d) {return d[0];}).y(function(d) { return d[1]; });
chart.yAxis
.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

chart.y2Axis
.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

chart.xAxis
.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%H:%M:%Z')(new Date(d)) });

chart.x2Axis
.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%H:%M:%Z')(new Date(d)) });

d3.select('#chart svg')
.datum(data)
.transition().duration(500)
.call(chart);

return chart;
```

Comment: Is the server generating the graph data in CMT+3 or in UTC?

Comment: the server generate it on UTC and the client in UTC+02:00

Comment: but the problem is the project should be working on different time zones at the same time

Comment: the i want the graph to be always on the server-side time zone (thats not a problem to send the timezone to the client) i just dont know how to change  the data to b on the server side timezone.

Comment: Could you put an example online on jsFiddle with some sample data? With a live example it should be doable to find a solution.

Comment: sure! https://jsfiddle.net/onhf5uwz/

Comment: Overall I don't understand why `chart.xAxis.scale(d3.time.scale.utc())` doesn't work. I hope someone else can help you.

Answer (score 2):

found a solution !

```
 var now =new Date();
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {  if (d!= undefined) 
    { 
    return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d+ now.getTimezoneOffset() *             60000  +Number(timeZoneOffset) )) }
});
```